# How can I make a window display 1/4 of screen in a corner with combo keys?

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, window

In Windows, if I press `win`+`left`, the current window will be moved to the left side of the screen, taking up 1/2 of the screen; if I further press `win`+`up`, the window will be moved to the top-left corner, taking up 1/4 of the screen.

But in ubuntu 20.04 only the first step is possible. Can I configure my computer to do the second step?

P.S. Not sure what the `win` button is called if I use ubuntu.

---

**update**: For anyone still interested, another option is to use kubuntu. One can set the hotkeys in "global shortcuts -> kwin -> quick tile..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunatelly (and quite difficult to understand), quarter tiling is not a feature of the current Gnome Shell desktop. However, there is a Gnome Shell extension,  [WinTile: Windows 10 window tiling for GNOME by Fmstrat](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1723/wintile-windows-10-window-tiling-for-gnome/), that does exactly what you want: implement Windows 10 style tiling and quarter tiling.

Comment: Sadly WinTile does not allow changing hotkeys. I have configured my gestures program to use certain hotkeys and I don't want to change that